# Sym jet sport 50cc 2 stroke cutting out

Tags: sparkplugs, carburetor

Starts up fine from cold, can ride it for around 5mins then cuts out and won’t start until cold, it’s got a good spark, competition and is getting fuel. I’ve change the spark plug, ht lead and automatic choke but still dose it. Can anyone suggest on what it could be.
Thanks In advanced

Comment: I'll assume you mean "compression" not "competition"?  Please edit the post.

Comment: Does the fuel cap provide venting? Try this next time it's warm and not running - loosen the fuel cap and try starting.